# what is the equivalent to moveNext,movePrevois of the old vb6 in vb .net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I designed a program in vb6 which lets the user navigate through the table. now I am transferring this software to vb .net.now my question is how to perform these functionalities in vb .net.
here is my code that opens the database

```
Dim constr As String = "data source=DESKTOP-MDOP24U\GORASHY;" & "initial catalog=test;integrated security=SSPI;"
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(constr)
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * from 
words")
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = con
        con.Open()
Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
sdr.Read()
TextBox1.Text = sdr("word-no").ToString
TextBox2.Text = sdr("word").ToString
```

Answer (score 1):

Acctually, you can use what is VERY simular to a recordset in vb.net.

Hence, you can have say this code:

```
    Dim constr As String = "data source=DESKTOP-MDOP24U\GORASHY;" & "initial catalog=test;integrated security=SSPI;"

    Dim rstData As New DataTable

    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM words")
            con.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    If rstData.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = rstData.Rows(0)("word-no")
        TextBox2.Text = rstData.Rows(0)("word")
    End If
```

And say to loop each row, then this:

```
    For Each OneRow As DataRow In rstData.Rows
        Debug.Print($"Value of word-no = {OneRow("word-no")}")
    Next
```

And I suppose you could use a "index" loop, say like this:

```
    For i = 0 To rstData.Rows.Count - 1
        Debug.Print($"Value of word-no = {rstData.Rows(i)("word-no")}")
    Next
```

And you can even use the datatable much like a reocrdset, and update the rows, and then send back to the table.

So, say then this:

```
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM words")
            con.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

            For Each OneRow As DataRow In rstData.Rows
                OneRow("word") = "Hello"
            Next

            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim daU As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
            da.Update(rstData)

        End Using
    End Using
```

So, the above would loop each row, set the column "word" to hello, and then write all the rows back to the database.

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET works quite differently to ADO. An ADO `Recordset` maintained an open connection to the database so when you edited or navigated through the data, you were changing and seeing what was actually in the database. ADO.NET works in a disconnected state. You open a connection, retrieve data from the database, close the connection, use and/or modify the data, open a connection, save the changes and then close the connection. Navigation and modification are performed on a local copy of the data that is disconnected from the database.

The `SqlDataReader` that you're using (as with all ADO.NET data readers) provides read-only, forward-only access to the result set of a query. Each time you call `Read`, it will get the next record in that result set. That is something like the `moveNext` that you want but there is no equivalent to `movePrevious` and you cannot make any changes to the data and have that affect the database.

What you should be doing is populating a `DataTable` with the result set of your query, binding that to a `BindingSource` and binding that to your control(s). You can then call `MoveNext` and `MovePrevious` on the `BindingSource` to navigate the data in the `DataTable` and automatically populate the control(s). Any changes you make to the data in the control(s) will be automatically pushed to the `DataTable` and you can then save those changes back to the database if desired.

If you don't intend to save any changes, you can use a data reader to populate the `DataTable`:

```vb
Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString),
      command As New SqlCommand(query, connection)
    connection.Open()

    Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
        Dim table As New DataTable

        table.Load(reader)
        myBindingSource.DataSource = table
        myTextBox.DataBindingS.Add("Text", myBindingSource, "SomeColumn")
    End Using
End Using
```

If you do want to edit the data and save the changes, you should use a data adapter:

```vb
Private adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString)
Private builder As New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
Private table As New DataTable

Private Sub GetData()
    adapter.Fill(table)
    myBindingSource.DataSource = table
    myTextBox.DataBindingS.Add("Text", myBindingSource, "SomeColumn")
End Sub

Private Sub SaveData()
    Validate()
    myBindingSource.EndEdit()
    adapter.Update(table)
End Sub
```

I have taken the easy option and used a command builder there but you may need to create the `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and/or `DeleteCommand` of the data adapter yourself, depending on the situation. That is beyond the scope of this answer.

In both cases, you should add the `BindingSource` to the form in the designer. You can then call `MoveNext` and `MovePrevious` on the `BindingSource` on the `Click` of your own `Button` controls, or you can add a `BindingNavigator` and have it done automatically.